# Firestore query for array of documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, document

I am trying to develop an eCommerce app. Now I am stuck with data modeling.

my use case is, I am storing user document ids in a product document for the users who liked the product.
and in the admin dashboard, **I want to display the email of all the users who liked the product**.

**if I have the document ID of all the users, is there any way to query firestore with an array of document ids to get back all the user's emails who liked that product *in one query?***

I can loop over the Ids but that would be cumbersome and will take a lot of time (not efficient).

Any Suggestion??

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use `in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to query for up to 10 [document ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#static-documentid) values. If you have more than 10 values, you'll need to execute a separate query for each (up to) 10, and then merge the results client-side.